# Calculating the standard deviation involving a moment generating function

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, actuarial-science, variance

An actuary determines that the claim size for a certain class of accidents is a random variable, X, with moment generation function:
$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{(1-2500t)^4}.$$
Calculate the standard deviation of the claim size for this class of accidents.

(Note: the shortcut for this question is seeing that it's a gamma distribution function with parameters 4 and 2500. Therefore, Var(X) will be $4\cdot 2500^2 = 25,000,000$ and the standard deviation will then be $\sqrt{25,000,000} = 5,000$. However, let's assume we cannot see this.)

From I understand, the SD can be found by doing this calculation:

$$SD(X)=\sqrt{M''(0)-[M'(0)]^2}$$
The reason to that is because $SD(X)=\sqrt{Var(X)}=\sqrt{E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2}$ and $E(X^n) = M^n(0)$.

($M^n(0)$ is the derivative of $M(X)$ to the $n$-th time at $0$)

Why is $E(X^n) = M^n(0)$ true?

Comment: By the way, for variance you want $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was what I meant.

Comment: It might not be called the *moment generating function* if this or something like it was not true.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. I read this paper and it cleared things up for me: [ELEMENTS OF PROBABILITY DISTRIBUTION THEORY](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~bb/MS_Lectures_5and6.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $M(t)=\int_\Omega e^{tX}dP$. Then, $M^{(n)}(t)=\int_\Omega X^ne^{tX}dP$ (it follows by differentiated $n$ times) Then, $M^{(n)}(0)=\int_\Omega X^ndP$, and the last is precisly $E[X^n]$.

Comment: provided you can differentiate under the integral.

Comment: @snarfblaat that's right.